# Running Java GDAL JNI on Scala sbt 1.0.3

Tags: java, scala, java-native-interface, sbt, gdal

Encountering this error when running GDAL JNI bindings on Scala SBT 1.0.3, Scala 2.11.12. I tried all 2.X.X versions of gdal found in (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gdal/gdal) but nothing helps. I'm running this on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V
[error] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V
[error]         at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister(Native Method)
[error]         at org.gdal.gdal.gdal.AllRegister(gdal.java:493)
[error]         at demo.Main$.main(Main.scala:224)
[error]         at demo.Main.main(Main.scala)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error]         at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:89)
[error]         at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:83)
[error]         at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:73)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
[error]         at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[debug]         Thread run-main-0 exited.
```

Ran sbt with both fork := true/false, error happens on both instances

I've tried several methods of adding the GDAL jar file into the classpath including during runtime as suggested in (http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7542.html#comment-31218) but to no avail.

It was mentioned in (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/358) that adding a -nobootcp option might help, but since Build.scala has been deprecated, I need to revert to a version of SBT older than 0.13, which I can't due to library dependencies.

I've also tried adding "-nobootcp" to scalacOptions, still nothing. Has anyone encountered this issue and what were the steps you did to solve it?

**EDIT**

My OS's GDAL version is 1.11.3, currently trying to revert to a compatible version of Java bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit. libgdal's JNI .so files are installed in /usr/lib/jni/*, but the path needs to be added java's classpath explicitly. The directory structure is shown below.

```
/usr/lib/libgdal.a
/usr/lib/libgdal.so
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1.18.3
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.20.3.1
/usr/lib/jni/libgdalconstjni.so
/usr/lib/jni/libgdalconstjni.so.20
/usr/lib/jni/libgdaljni.so
/usr/lib/jni/libgdaljni.so.20
/usr/lib/ogdi/libgdal.so
```